# Docker Service failed to build: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project that contains a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml`.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"

services:
  front:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
```

When I try to run it like below.

> docker-compose up -d

I get the following message:

```
Building front
Step 1/8 : FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS builder
 ---> 5ff13b69f215
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1da7c0d4dfac
Step 3/8 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d82bb9c0ecf
Step 4/8 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e557a2dbe03
Step 5/8 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea2d3f56ff39
Step 6/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1edb82c45c49
Step 7/8 : COPY --from=builder /app/build .
ERROR: Service 'front' failed to build: invalid from flag value builder: pull access denied for builder, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I saw another question on Stackoverflow, I think it may be close to my problem.
[invalid from flag value build: pull access denied for build, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034633/invalid-from-flag-value-build-pull-access-denied-for-build-repository-does-not)

But I only have a build stage, not two stage like in the question from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker build is failing because you are missing a `FROM` command for your runtime environment.  This appears to be a [multi-stage docker build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), and you are attempting to copy files from a previous build stage named `builder` but you are still in the first (and only) stage of your build (which is called builder).

You have two options.  Either one should work.

1. Introduce a second runtime stage to your build:

Add another `FROM` command with the image that you want as your runtime.  I just used `mhart/alpine-node:11` again here but you may want a different runtime environment.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS runtime
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

2. Make it a non multi-stage build:

Just remove the `COPY` command and change your workdir to the build directory:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS builder
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
WORKDIR /app/build
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

Comment: Hello both of your answer, help me building the docker, but I get the error:
ERROR: for front_student_front_1  Cannot start service front: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "serve": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown. 
I tried to search for this error, but to no avail

Comment: @Hamza Ince  Ok cool, so it's building now but your 'CMD' is off.  Do you know what 'serve' is supposed to be?  Is it a binary that is output by your build process?  If so you probably just need to change 'CMD' to use './serve' instead of 'serve'.  Are you following a guide or something?

Comment: Ok I found it, I had to install serve with yarn, I hope you don't mind if I edit your answer.